# Need of Regular Expression patttern for certain condition

Tags: php, jquery, regex

How  to create regular expression with below conditions?

1. MIN PASSWORD LENGTH:  8
2. MIN NUMBER OF CHARACTERS:1
3. MIN NUMBER OF DIGITS:  1
4. MIN NUMBER OF SPECIAL CHARACTERS: 1
5. MAX REPEATING CHARACTERS: 2
6. MAX ALPHABETICAL ORDER: 2
7. MAX NUMERICAL ORDER:  2

Tried:

```
^(?=(.*\d){1})(?=.*[!@#$%_-]) (?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z]){1,2}.{8,}$
```

Comment: can you give some example??

Comment: There is no close vote option any more for *"not enough effort or solution attempt"*? What to do with questions like these? Answer or request more of the OP, or close vote for something? (I guess this belongs on meta.)

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, include it in your question.

Comment: @Qtax i agree with with u mate we are not here to code for any one else we can solve problem not to code for them

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't go about trying to do all of that in one regular expression. Why don't you just test for each thing one by one? What language are you using?

Comment: @emh I have tried -> ^(?=(.*\d){1})(?=.*[!@#$%_-]) (?=.*[0-9a-zA-Z]){1,2}.{8,}$ , i need for maximum repeating characters ,alpha * numerical order

Comment: @TomFenech Im using php with jquery.

Comment: you might want to consider splitting the lookaheads in the given answers into separate expressions evaluated separately. That way you can tell the user what the specific problem is with the password.

Comment: @user2677640 Thanks, added that to the question. Please do that in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do this (and I'm assuming by letters/digits you mean ASCII letters/digits), but your last two requirements won't be simple:

```
if (preg_match(
    '/^              # Start of string
    (?=.*[a-z])      # Assert at least one letter
    (?=.*[0-9])      # and one digit
    (?=.*[^a-z0-9])  # and one "other" character
    (?!.*(.)\1{2})   # and no three identical characters in a row
    (?!.*(?:abc|bcd|cde|def|efg|fgh|ghi|
            hij|ijk|jkl|klm|lmn|mno|nop|
            opq|pqr|qrs|rst|stu|tuv|uvw|
            vwx|wxy|xyz)) # and no three-letter sequence
    (?!.*(?:123|234|345|456|567|678|789|890))  # and no three-digit sequence
    .{8,}            # Match at least 8 characters
    $                # End of string/ix',       
    $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

If you also want to exclude letters/digits in descending order (or wraparounds like `zab` or `901`) you'll need to add them to the alternations.

Comment: I wish I would have refreshed this while writing almost the exact same answer! You beat me to it! The only significant difference in my answer was explicitly specifying special characters `[!@#$%_-]` as in OP's example.